# Showing certaing Integral domain is not well ordered.

Tags: ring-theory, order-theory, integral-domain

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=\{ a+b\sqrt2 ~| a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\} $ be an integral domain.

Let $p=\{ a+b\sqrt2 ~|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}  ~~~ and ~~~ a+b\sqrt 2 ~~is~~a~positive~real~number \} $

Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ is ordered Integral Domain but not well-ordered with respect to $p$.
I know how to show that it is ordered with resp. to $p$ but I'm not able to show that it is not well ordered with resp. to $p$.(I couldn't find a subset of $p$ that doesn't have a least element).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If we take $x\in \mathbb{Z[\sqrt2]}$ only one of the following holds $x\in  P$, $x=0$ or $-x\in p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to show that $p$ is not well-ordered, is to show that $p$ has no minimal element. This is trivial once you note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{2}-1)^n = 0$$

Comment: what if $p$ were defined as $P:=\{ a+b\sqrt7 ~|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}  ~~~ and ~~~ ab\sqrt 7 ~~is~~a~positive~real~number \}$?

Comment: $ab\sqrt{7} > 0$ if and only if $ab >0$. So for example, for $a,b <0$ you have no minimum.